# Postgres order by uses indexes wrongly

Tags: database, performance, postgresql

Well there are questions out there which says postgres does not use order by but my case is where it uses wrongly.

Sorting without index - hot run after results are cached.Takes 8.48 Seconds

```
explain (analyze,buffers) select * from users order by userid limit 100000;
                                                           QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=246372.98..246622.98 rows=100000 width=72) (actual time=8451.119..8479.138 rows=100000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=16134 read=35121
   ->  Sort  (cost=246372.98..251348.03 rows=1990021 width=72) (actual time=8451.117..8467.403 rows=100000 loops=1)
         Sort Key: userid
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 20207kB
         Buffers: shared hit=16134 read=35121
         ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..71155.21 rows=1990021 width=72) (actual time=25.448..7782.830 rows=1995958 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=16134 read=35121
 Planning time: 40.542 ms
 Execution time: 8487.556 ms
(10 rows)
```

Sorting with index on userid column.Users more disk I/O and takes a whopping 6.2 Mins

```
explain (analyze,buffers) select * from users order by userid limit 100000;
                                                                     QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..12771.83 rows=100000 width=72) (actual time=35.498..372437.748 rows=100000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=60846 read=39425
   ->  Index Scan using users_userid_idx on users  (cost=0.43..255288.96 rows=1998907 width=72) (actual time=35.496..372372.192 rows=100000 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=60846 read=39425
 Planning time: 0.160 ms
 Execution time: 372476.536 ms
(6 rows)
```

Few things to note

- I ran Vacuum analyze before both the queries were run.
- Both were hot runs i.e I took them after running 3-4 times
- There was enough work mem, it uses a top-N heapsort.Although the problem is the sorting without index is way faster.

My question is not to improve order by, but to understand why the planner estimates wrongly.At the moment of writing this question I ran these queries on my Mac OSx on postgres 9.4.I do not have any other machines with different OS to test at the moment, maybe ill do it soon.

Can anyone else confirm if this is a bug with the planner, or is it something wrong with my machine.

Comment: Has `vacuum analyze` finished normally without problems or errors?

Answer (score 1):

I am totally stumped on what actually happened.Here are the new stats after I did the following steps.

- Restarted my Mac
- Changed shared buffers to 256 MB (previous was 128 MB)
- Restarted postgres

After I did these, here are the new stats.

```
explain (analyze,buffers) select * from users order by userid limit 100000;
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..12788.49 rows=100000 width=72) (actual time=0.031..78.785 rows=100000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=100271
   ->  Index Scan using users_userid_idx on users  (cost=0.43..255244.73 rows=1995958 width=72) (actual time=0.030..65.937 rows=100000 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=100271
 Planning time: 0.119 ms
 Execution time: 84.985 ms
(6 rows)
```

The only change is there is no disk I/O since everything is cached, may be because of increased shared buffers.But the actual time variation is beyond logic.

The normal top-N heapsort without index has also improved.

```
                                                          QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=246955.09..247205.09 rows=100000 width=72) (actual time=707.350..734.954 rows=100000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=26071 read=25184
   ->  Sort  (cost=246955.09..251944.99 rows=1995958 width=72) (actual time=707.348..723.127 rows=100000 loops=1)
         Sort Key: userid
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 20207kB
         Buffers: shared hit=26071 read=25184
         ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..71214.58 rows=1995958 width=72) (actual time=9.922..270.684 rows=1995958 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=26071 read=25184
 Planning time: 0.090 ms
 Execution time: 743.788 ms
(10 rows)
```

With the shared buffers changed back to 128 MB, the results are still good.

```
explain (analyze,buffers) select * from users order by userid limit 100000;
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..12788.49 rows=100000 width=72) (actual time=0.098..232.314 rows=100000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=61313 read=38958
   ->  Index Scan using users_userid_idx on users  (cost=0.43..255244.73 rows=1995958 width=72) (actual time=0.096..218.272 rows=100000 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=61313 read=38958
 Planning time: 0.131 ms
 Execution time: 238.861 ms
(6 rows)


explain (analyze,buffers) select * from users order by userid limit 100000;
                                                          QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=246955.09..247205.09 rows=100000 width=72) (actual time=722.003..749.696 rows=100000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=16192 read=35063
   ->  Sort  (cost=246955.09..251944.99 rows=1995958 width=72) (actual time=722.001..737.715 rows=100000 loops=1)
         Sort Key: userid
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 20207kB
         Buffers: shared hit=16192 read=35063
         ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..71214.58 rows=1995958 width=72) (actual time=8.584..294.605 rows=1995958 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=16192 read=35063
 Planning time: 0.070 ms
 Execution time: 757.495 ms
(10 rows)
```

I have heard people saying not to take timing results on Mac/desktop machines, but this is totally insane.

Comment: Yeah, that's nuts. I was wondering if the index was badly bloated and if a `reindex` would help (though it shouldn't be required). That still wouldn't explain just *how bad* this was. The fact that it all sped up across the board is particularly odd. There's something really weird going on here, possibly at the kernel level. If it happens again it'd be interesting to try to observe vmstat and see if it's CPU-bound, doing lots of I/O, etc.

Comment: Surely ill do that.I had a chance to test the same with another powerful machine which runs Cent OS, but I could not reproduce the same problem there, so there is definitely something that happened in my machine.